# Monitor memory usage from process beginning to end

Tags: c++, memory-management, process, cpu-usage

I would like to monitor a processes' CPU and Memory usage (usage, heap allocations, locations, etc...) from the time the process begins until it exits.

For example:

> monitorProcess.exe myProcess.exe --myProcessParameter 123

Are there any tools (preferably open source) that perform this?

Alternatively, what key API functions should I research to do this myself?

I'm not looking for Process Explorer or something like that. I want to attach it to a specific process and monitor only that one.

Comment: Why the immediate downvote with no explanation? I've googled various formulations of this question and I run into "process explorer" after "task manager" after "top" etc...

Comment: I can only guess, but probably because you haven't done much to define exactly what about the process you want to monitor, whether you want to display it real-time, or just collect a summary when it exits, etc. You probably also need to specify the operating system you want to target.

Answer (score 0):

[Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) has a tool for this, it is called Massif.